Fontello not rendering correctly
About 1 in every 30 refreshes, fontello does not render correctly (happens across multiple web pages).
Here is an example (top wrong, bottom correct):

Anyone know what causes this?
I'm using the latest version of Chrome on windows (124.0).
The font is the first thing to be loaded before anything else (JS, Google fonts etc).
Thanks in advance
